# UnicodeDecodeError for file when opening in linux but same file opens in windows

Tags: python, unicode, decode

```py
f.open(filename,'r',-1,'utf-8')
print(f.readline())
```

This code reads the file line by line in windows but same code gives `UnicodeDecodeError` when trying in linux.

Comment: Can you please add the full error message also in the question?

Comment: Are you certain it's the same file? We are going to need some sort of [mcve]

Comment: If you write `encoding`='utf-8'` there is no need to pass the `-1`. I know it's not shorter, but avoids the magic number `-1` .

Comment: What is `f` on the first line here?